# Unity Build - Keep Window When Maximizing

Tags: unity-game-engine

I've set my "Fullscreen Mode" in Player Settings to "Windowed" (and tried all the other options just in case), and not a single option seems to keep my window bars when I maximize. I've had to work around it and add my own ugly minimize and close buttons when it's maximized just so I can still have those options. What can I do to keep the window, bars, and buttons? Is Unity bugging when making my build or am I misunderstanding how this is supposed to work? I'm using Unity 2018.3.8f1, btw.

Comment: This may help.https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/FullScreenMode.html

Comment: As I said, I tried all of those options. Why the heck is this flagged as a bad question?

Comment: Well it is simply made this way .. FullScreen means extend to the full display size without being a window anymore.. what you would actually want is [MaximizedWindow](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/FullScreenMode.MaximizedWindow.html) which is only available on mac

Comment: It was just a bug in Unity 2018.3.8f1. Fixed in 2018.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems to be the [MAXIMIZED WINDOW FUNCTIONALITY IS BROKEN](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/fullscreen-mode-maximized-window-functionality-is-broken-and-any-built-player-changes-to-non-window-mode-when-maximizing) issue, which is found in Unity 2018.3.8f1. 
Solution is to upgrade Unity or try their proposed workaround found [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/unity-2019-1-is-now-available.661885/page-3#post-4491478)

Comment: Would this mean it's only a problem for my computer? So if I have "Maximized Window" selected and give the build to a new computer to use, it would be fine for them but bad for me? Or is my own registry corrupting the executable?

Comment: Deleting the reg entries (or running for the first time), building with `Fullscreen Window` and having `Screen.fullScreen = false;` somewhere in your code also gives  you a maximized window.

Comment: Deleting the reg entries (or running for the first time), building with `Windowed` and `Resizable Window` in player settings starts the game in a window which you can maximize.

Comment: the only issue with setting Screen.fullScreen = false after maximizing it, is that it doesn't take the window size into account nor the Task Bar. I'd like it to fill the screen perfectly just like if I maximize Chrome. Maybe I can know the location/size of the quick launch and subtract and reposition?

Comment: @CodeMonkey buiding with `Windowed` and `Resizable Window` and clicking the maximize button would work exactly  like chrome. Maybe you ran into [this issue](https://issuetracker.unity3d.com/issues/fullscreen-mode-maximized-window-functionality-is-broken-and-any-built-player-changes-to-non-window-mode-when-maximizing)? It says  it's still Found in 2018.3.8f1.

Comment: Sounds promising... I'm updating to 2019.3.4f1 and hoping it breaks nothing. Wish me luck! :-)

Comment: Ugh. No luck updating to 2019. It just kept hanging trying to load package manager. BUT, I did get 2018.4 and it solved the issue! Now I feel stupid though for thinking I was stupid rather than it being a bug with Unity... Still, if you want to write the answer to Upgrade, I will accept and award. Thanks!